# I want to write a class which dynamically add the views like button or TextView or

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, dynamic, view

I want to write a class which dynamically add the views like button or TextView or ...

I did it but there is some problem

1- I want to use an option that means I want to use **scroll** or I want to show all of the views in the screen.

1-1 I want to use scroll (Vertical or Horizontal) to show all of the views.

1-2 I want to use **android:layout_weight** to fit the views in the same size which are beautiful on screen on any size of screen but I don't know how.
m=number of rows
n=number of columns

2- I don't know is it a good method for describing a class for considering the **Object Oriented Concepts**

In XML file there is only a **RelativeLayout**.

**the Class:**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MakeTwoDimensionArrayView {
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
    private LinearLayout [] subLinearLayout;
    MakeTwoDimensionArrayView(Context c, int m, int n, ArrayList<?> V){
        scrollView=new ScrollView(c);
        mainLinearLayout=new LinearLayout(c);
        mainLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mainLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        subLinearLayout=new LinearLayout[m];
        scrollView.addView(mainLinearLayout);
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
            subLinearLayout[i]=new LinearLayout(c);
            subLinearLayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            subLinearLayout[i].setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                int t=i*n+j;
                View v= (View) V.get(t);
                v.setTag(t+"");
                subLinearLayout[i].addView(v);
            }
            mainLinearLayout.addView(subLinearLayout[i]);
        }
    }

    public ScrollView getLayout(){
        return scrollView;
    }
}
```

**The main**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MakeTwoDimensionArrayView makeButton;
    ArrayList <Button> buttons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int m=3, n=2;

        buttons=new ArrayList<Button>();
        for (int i=0; i<m*n; i++){
            Button b=new Button(this);
            buttons.add(b);
        }
        makeButton=new MakeTwoDimensionArrayView(this, m, n, buttons);
        setContentView(makeButton.getLayout());
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement horizontalScrollView within scrollView. and in that horizontalScrollView add buttons. then it will be both vertically and horizontally scrollable. But for that you should know about [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html). because they have only one direct child layout. This is an XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itemContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="Item1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="Item2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="Item3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="Item3" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is only demo for you to understand how scrollView and horizontalScrollView works in an xml if you want to implement dynamically then change in your MakeTwoDimensionArrayView class and in `onCreate()` of activity class. if still you have question then let me know.

Comment: Thank you.
I learned something but I need something else.
Consider that we look at the big image on cellphone, we can navigate all part of the photo by dragging.
I want do it for the views (like buttons).
or by using the proerty **Weight** fitting all of the buttons on screen.